# Scala - return geometric sequence

Tags: scala

I would like a way (in Scala) to compute the geometric sequence given the starting number, scale factor, and size.

For instances, starting value of 1, scale factor of 2, size of 5 produces a list or sequence:

```
1 2 4 8 16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `Stream.iterate(1)(_*2).take(5).toList`

Comment: What if my values are in Double?

Comment: Simple - `Stream.iterate(1.0)(_*2).take(5).toList`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stream` in **Scala**:

```
scala> val TWO = BigInt(2)
scala> Stream.from(0).map(x => TWO.pow(x)) take 5 toList

res: List[scala.math.BigInt] = List(1, 2, 4, 8, 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `scanLeft`, partial results are accumulated into the resulting collection, hence consider

```
(1 to 4).scanLeft(1)( (a,_) => a*2)
```

The lambda function includes a value denoted by `a` for the accumulated result up to the *current* iteration, which is factored by `2`. The scanning starts with initial value `1` and performs four additional results (up to the 5th item).

Comment: If you're not using the accumulator I don't see any reason to choose `scanLeft` over more idiomatic options.